# Is it possible to install postgresql on windows 7 home premium?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, installation

I am trying to install postgreSQL for a flask project. Towards the end of the installation I get this error message: "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Failed to start the database server."
If I'm lucky I can get get a different error message to pop up.

here are some links to things that I have tried.

1. https://help.statlook.com/knowledge-base/problem-running-post-install-step-postgresql-installation
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS_zWDDDSe0
3. https://webkul.com/blog/postgresql-windows-installation-problem-running-post-install-step-installation-may-not-complete-correctly/
4. [postgresql installation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656410/postgresql-installation-failed)
5. [postgres installation the database cluster initialization failed ( Postgresql Version 9.4.4 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453451/postgres-installation-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed-postgresql-ve)

I have tried installing other versions.

- postgresql-11.2-2-windows-x64

  - I found in the beginning that this one is wrong for my version of windows.
- postgresql-10.7-2-windows-x64
- postgresql-9.6.12-2-windows-x64
- postgresql-10.7-2-windows

**Update:** I knew that the computer name couldn't have spaces but I just found out that it can't have dashes either... it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer name can't have spaces or dashes.